# Highlight heredoc as perl code

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I would like to highlight all the HereDocs in a particular perl file as perl code. For example, I'd like to apply the normal perl highlighting to the subroutine in this HereDoc:

```
my $code = <<'CODE';
   sub test {
      say "this is a test";
   };
CODE
```

I thought I could do this with something like:

```
syn region perlHereDocPL    start=+<<\s*'\z([^\\']*\%(\\.[^\\']*\)*\)'+ matchgroup=perlSnip end=+^\z1$+ contains=@perlTop
```

But apparently this doesn't work like I thought it did. Thanks!

Comment: Does this file already have some other syntax highlighting applied to it?

Comment: Yes, it is a perl test file. Perl syntax highlighted.

Comment: Right, so you want to highlight Perl code inside Perl code *[insert snarky comment about Perl readability]* :p

Comment: Typically the heredoc would be formatted as a string. For this particular file, I want to format it as perl. I've seen similar configurations, i.e. javascript inside an <script> tag in an HTML file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like I found a solution. I was able to adapt config that formatted heredoc as SQL:

```
" .vim/after/syntax/perl/heredoc-perl.vim
runtime! syntax/perl.vim
unlet b:current_syntax
syntax include @Perl syntax/perl.vim

syntax region sqlSnip matchgroup=Snip start=+<<['"]RAW['"].*;\s*$+ end=+^\s*RAW$+ contains=@Perl
syntax region sqlSnip matchgroup=Snip start=+<<['"]TIDIED['"].*;\s*$+ end=+^\s*TIDIED$+ contains=@Perl
```

This only applies to heredocs that are identified by RAW or TIDIED, but that is perfect for my purposes.

Comment: I think you can lose the first two lines here (`runtime! syntax/sql.vim`, `unlet b:current_syntax`)? As you're not doing anything with the SQL syntax...

Comment: Thanks. That should have been `runtime! syntax/perl.vim` instead of `runtime! syntax/sql.vim`. That probably isn't necessary either since the rest of the file is using the perl syntax.